# Angular.js - View doesn't update when changing a scope variable in resize event

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to change the scope variable `tab` to "home" every time the window size got changed. The following code does it well, but for some reason, the view doesn't get updated.

```js
$scope.changeTab = function (tab) {
  $scope.tab = tab;
};
    
angular.element($window).bind('resize', function () {
  $scope.changeTab('home');
});
```

```html
<div>{{ tab }}</div>
```

Comment: Could you post your code to jsfiddle or plunker?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should wrap your `$scope.closeMoreTab();` into `$scope.$apply` function, as this currently changes value, but doesn't trigger digest cycle:

```
angular.element($window).bind('resize', function() {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.closeMoreTab();
    });
});
```

Comment: Using `$timeout` instead of `$scope.$apply` is safer. `$scope.$apply` can led to digest issues.

Comment: @KursadGulseven It can but usually, one knows the context its being used. In this case, its being called outside of angular which is safe. If the case was that it might be called inside of angular world sometimes and sometimes not, then timeout might be a better bet.

Comment: Confirmed correct with [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/troygizzi/0owft2cs/). However, I also added two other little changes for the OP to consider: (1) an example of throttling as a "best practice" when handling frequently-fired events like a window resize, and (2) an example of unbinding an event handler that is "idempotent" and therefore only needs to be called the first time it's triggered. Note that the throttling example is commented out in that fiddle, because for this particular case, unbinding makes more sense than merely throttling.

Answer (score -1):

You may try to add variable to `$watch`, as whenever value changes of that variable, `$apply` will get called, and calling `$apply` will take care of `$digest` cycle.